# Change MasterViewController TabBarItem label from another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, master-detail

I'm using a Master Detail template. In the storyboard, I've attached a TabBarItem ( Login ) unto the MasterViewController where the segue for the Login is a Popover Presentation to a LoginViewController which in turn has a Button.

What I'm trying to achieve is in the LoginView, upon clicking on that button, the TabBarItem text changes to Logout.

I have included a LoginViewController.swift and added a IBAction that hooks up with the Button. However, this is the part that I'm banging my head on the desk as I've tried searching Swift related suggestions and came up with nothing.

I've included a link of the layout screenshot in case I'm not making any sense.

[image: screenshot]

The image might look a bit small, the [link for full image](http://briskpartner.com/so/img/changelabel.png)

This is my first time coding for IOS, hence, I have extremely limited knowledge and experience with Swift, any help is appreciated.

---

LoginViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {
        let items = self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]
        println("items: \(items)")
       // items[0].title = "Logout"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add this, when you want to change the tabBar title.

```
let items = self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem]
items[1].title = "Logout"
```

items is an array of all tabBar items, and through this array, you can change every tabBar item's properties, like the image, title etc.

Comment: I got this error when I attempted to put your code into my LoginViewController.swift.... fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value... below is the source code I used to hook up with the Login button in LoginViewController storyboard
@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {
        let items = self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]
        println("items: \(items)")
}

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but won't self be referring to LoginViewController instead of MasterViewController since LoginViewController is currently being invoked?

Comment: Yes you are right, but you can access your tabBar controller with  .tabBarController, and then change the tabbar items as you wish from all children, that are connected to the tabBar. You can also change tha tabbar from MasterViewController

Comment: I've tried your method, but the error message I've gotten is this: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) ... In the mean time, I've also edited by question to include the code for LoginViewController.swift

Comment: You are getting this error, because you are trying to acces an item, that doesnt exist. If you have 2 view controllers connectet to the tabbar controller, and you want to change the value of the second, you use: items[1].title...

Comment: Should it really be a TabBarController? The reason why I ask this is because Login is a BarButton in the Navigation Controller which is embedded into a TableViewController, sorry for asking all this simple questions  as I've tried searching and reading up on some Swift Tutorial books and nothing similar shows up

Answer (score 0):

Rather than banging the head onto the same spot in the brickwall over and over again, I've switched the approach to resolve the problem using delegate.

It does help to solve the problem but as I'm very new to Swift, I do not know the costs involved. But thank you to you nonetheless, Dejan. =D